# How does a single-node system get Availability in CAP theorem?

Tags: high-availability, distributed-system, availability, cap-theorem

I have a question. I read many blogs, websites about CAP theorem. They say that single-node systems are CA, but how can it be "A" if that single node goes down ? Because if it does, the system will be **unavailable**, right ?
And is "availability" in CAP equal to "availability" in HA of distributed systems ?

Comment: i think this is covered by partition-*in*tolerance. partition tolerance basically means that the system is operational if parts of the system go down. if a single node system goes down, and it is not operational, then it is not partition tolerant.

Comment: also, i think that this question should be moved to: [https://cs.stackexchange.com/](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Effie I have understood why it's not "P", but how about "A" ? if the single node system goes down, it will violate "A" ?

Comment: i guess it is consistent and available at all times at which there is no partition. and there is no guarantees about anything when there is a partition.

Comment: but you should move the question, i think there are people there who know better :)

Comment: @Effie I will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is not the definition of (cap) availability, it is not about being able to reply but refusing to do so, e.g. the node receives a message and it is not able to contact the rest of the cluster, what can it do: i) respond thereby becoming A but not C; ii) do not respond and become C but not A. See my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64427972/4828060) for illustrative examples.

As for your specific example I'm not sure it makes sense to reason about CAP if the cluster does not exist, I believe that you need at least one node.